# Dealing Age 3 - what to do with the two extra cards?

Tags: 7-wonders

How do you deal Age 3 of *7 Wonders*?

Once you get the deck ready for the adequate number of players and add the guilds, there ends up being 2 extra cards due to the 2+ guild logic. Thus some players would get more than 7 cards.

How is this handled? Are the extra cards simply not dealt? Can you provide an example for 5 players please?

Answer (score 16):

There are no extra cards in a correctly prepared deck.

The base game contains:

- 49 Age I cards
- 49 Age II cards
- 50 Age III cards

(There is one additional Age III card so that there are never *all* Guild cards in play.)

For a game with 5 players, you have 35 cards per Age:

- Age I: 35 non-Guild cards
- Age II: 35 non-Guild cards
- Age III: 28 non-Guild cards, 7 Guild cards

Comment: exactly.  every age, everyone will end up with EXACTLY 7 cards in their hand.  no more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

Guild cards are not all added together, you only add Guild cards based on the number of players +2, so you will always have a consistent amount of cards per player per age. In the case of the base game that will mean that you will always have 7 cards in your hand at the start of each age.

For 5 player game, that means 7 guild cards are added to the Age 3 cards.

This means you will have all the 3 player cards per age, all the 4 player cards, and all the 5 player cards. And the Age 3 deck will also have 7 guilds. (A total of 35 cards per Age)